# Create `~/.ssh/id_dsa` on a Windows machine for JSch

Tags: ssh, putty, jsch

I'm wondering is it possible to create this directory on a Windows machine `~/.ssh/id_dsa`? I have created a private key and wish to save it in a directory named `~/.ssh/id_dsa`. I've been told that `ssh-keygen -t rsa` this should work on the cmmand-line but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: `~` on Windows does not mean the home directory.

Comment: @PCLuddite He didn't ask what `~` means on Windows, he asked how to create such directory. `~` simply means "user's home directory". On Unix-like systems you would replace it with `/home/<username>`, on Windows systems with `c:\Users\<username>`. That's all.

Comment: BTW how is it related to Putty? `~/.ssh` is used by the OpenSSH. Putty is not even able to use the OpenSSH keys directly.

Comment: @PCLuddite BTW `~` means "*user's home directory*" in general. You can use it even on Windows systems, for example in Git bash.

Comment: I'm trying to use jsch to connect to a linux server which has a private/public key. For Jsch the private key that putty uses must be converted to OpenSSH. I've done that and when I run my java program it fails on an authentication problem. I'm hoping if I put the OpenSSH file in this directory's equivalent to ~/.ssh/id_ds it might work

Comment: @DawidFerenczy That's a program-specific implementation. `~` is not recognized by the Windows API as the home directory, and Windows programs that are not emulating some Unix-like features don't use it. That's all.

Comment: @PCLuddite sure, you're right, but that's completely irrelevant to the question. If he finds `~` for example in a documentation, he has to know that it means "*user's home directory*", which is `c:\Users\<username>` on Windows. That's all. Fact that you can use the `~` shortcut on some systems is nice, but you don't need it at all.

Comment: @PCLuddite My point is that I would understand from your first comment, that he simply can't create such directory on Windows. But that's not true. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~/.ssh/id_dsa` file is a default path to a private key used by OpenSSH SSH client on *nix systems. It has **nothing** to do with Windows or JSch.

The JSch uses a private key you specify using `addIdentity` method.

---

*Ntb, it's `id_dsa`, not `id_ds`. And it's a file, not a directory. And `ssh-keygen -t rsa` can hardly create `id_dsa`, the DSA and RSA are different algorithms. An `id_rsa` is used for RSA. But all this is irrelevant to your problem anyway.*

Comment: That key is used by OpenSSH packed with Git for Windows, or OpenSSH compiled using MinGW in general. `~` it translates to Windows user's profile. So that's for what it has to do with Windows. Other notes are valid, I didn't noticed these since it wasn't the main concern of his question.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy OpenSSH cannot run "on Windows". It runs on *nix emulation on Windows = Cygwin or MinGW. Cygwin or MinGW is what maps the `~` to Windows user's profile, not the Windows itself.

Comment: Sure, I know it, sorry if it wasn't clear from my comment. I use to use it everyday for more than 8 years already. BTW Cygwin does provide a POSIX environment (using `cygwin1.dll`), but MinGW doesn't. It's a toolchain which compiles into native Windows applications without any dependency on non-Windows libraries).

Answer (score 1):

`~` means the user's home directory. On Unix-like systems it's usually `/home/<username>`, on Windows systems (Vista and newer) it's `c:\Users\<username>`.

So just **create a directory `c:\Users\<username>\.ssh`**. I guess that `id_ds` is not a directory but file.

For example SSH packed with Git for Windows looks for `.ssh` directory exactly in that location. In general all binaries compiled using [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) expect it there.

BTW Windows equivalent of the `~` is `%HOMEPATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Do you think I have to add my openSHH file to %HOMEPATH% environment variable?

Comment: You should never use a hard coded path like `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh`. This might be the most likely place for the user's home directory, but it could technically be anywhere. Plus, there's no guarantee that `C:\Users` will be the default home directory in future versions of Windows. Use `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.ssh`

Comment: @PCLuddite First of all I'm mentioning it in my answer, but it's irrelevant to the question. He just needs to navigate to his home directory and create a subdirectory there. Why he should use an environment variable to get there? That's just for a use in some script or similar purpose.